# is it possible to execute a code inside an expression?

Tags: macros, julia, expression, metaprogramming

I have this macro:

```
 macro superM(name, field)
    :(struct $(esc(name))
    map(x -> (for i = 1:length(x) return  $(esc(x[i][1])) end),field.args)
    end)  
end

@superM test ((arg1,2),(arg2,4))
```

I just want to map the second argument to get the `arguments` for the `struct` in the macro.
So, this macro should define a struct like this:

```
struct test
 arg1 
 arg2
end
```

As I understand that I'm writing the map function inside an expression, that means my code will not execute and the map function will be a part of my struct. But is there any way to execute the map function inside the expression?
Here I got error:  `LoadError: UndefVarError:  x not defined`

Comment: When asking about a macro, please include what you want the macro to expand to.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the 2 and 4 for, it doesn't show up in the final struct

Comment: I added it just to show, that the tuple have more than one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
macro superM(name, field)
    code = Base.remove_linenums!(quote
           struct $name
           end
          end)
    append!(code.args[1].args[3].args,[f.args[1] for f in field.args])
    code
end
```

Now give it a spin:

```
julia> @macroexpand @superM(mysss,((field1,1),(field2,2)))
quote
    struct mysss
        field1
        field2
    end
end

julia> @superM(mysss,((field1,1),(field2,2)))

julia> mysss(1,5)
mysss(1, 5)

julia> dump(mysss(1,"ala"))
mysss
  field1: Int64 1
  field2: String "ala"
```